# PHP Socket define the max time to wait

Tags: php, sockets

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, $ip_server , $port);

socket_sendto($socket, $ascii_egyben_kimenet, strlen($ascii_egyben_kimenet), 0, $ip_plc , $port);
$valasz_kimenet=socket_read($socket, 256);
```

Because the socket_read the server is waiting for an answer...
How I can define the max time to wait?

Answer (score 2):

You do that with the function [`socket_set_timeout()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-timeout.php). Example for a 1/2 second timeout:

```
socket_set_timeout($socket, 0, 500);
```

You can check if someone is trying to connect without blocking by [setting the socket to non-blocking mode](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-blocking.php):

```
socket_set_blocking($socket, 0);
```

Comment: socket_set_timeout($socket, 3, 500);
where to put it?
I tried but not working.

Comment: You should set the timeout value before you call socket_read(). If it really does not work, you should enable error_reporting(E_ALL)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the same problem shows up with socket_set_timeout(), but with serious use of stream_set_timeout(), I found that PHP was setting the time limit at double what I specified.  So if I told it 60 seconds, it actually was exactly two minutes before I stopped listening.  I actually had to take the number of seconds desired and multiply by 500000 to get the value to use in stream_set_timeout().

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>10, 'usec'=>0));
```